# How to trim image in the web-browser using js and save it on server then?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I'm looking for some jQuery plugin or smth similar.

For example, I need to crop a photo on website and to save the result on server.

[image]

I know that it is better to do it in Adobe Flash, but I really need to do in using JS.

Comment: Nothing is better in Adobe Flash. However, I think what you should do is crop the image on the server instead, where there are any number of PHP-based image manipulation libraries at your disposal.

Comment: @mblase75: except maybe a rectal exam by your friendly neighborhood TSA agent.

Comment: @mblase75 PHP-based is a good idea, but how to send a new parameters from browser then? Is there some js plugin to send it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [jCrop](http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/). It's perfect for this stuff.

Comment: JCrop is very good for picking the area to crop but does nothing to actually crop the image. You'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: @Cixate it crops exellent http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=live_crop. Isn't it?

Comment: It crops excellent, but does it by sending it to the server for PHP/gd to do the cropping. I was under the impression that you wanted to do the resizing/cropping in Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Very few browsers support selecting an image with Javascript and manipulating it without first uploading it to a server. Instead, you'll need to:

1. Allow user to upload image to server
2. When upload is complete, resize the image (with PHP) to a manageable size for the browser for preview
3. Show the resized preview image in the browser in something like [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)
4. After the user chooses the crop area, have them click "Save"
5. On Save, pass the coordinates of the cropped area to the server/PHP to have it crop the original image. You'll have to scale the coordinates for the preview to coordinates for the original image.
6. Save the new image to disk/S3/whatever with PHP

I managed to do this without ever using my server or having the image touch my server by using http://transloadit.com/. I use transloadit's Javascript upload form to upload to their server storage (S3) and use a template that saves the original and resizes for preview. Both the original and preview are stored in transloadit's temporary S3 account, not mine. I then use JCrop to show the user the preview. Once they select the crop area I then tell transloadit to crop the original photo but with my crop coordinates (scaled from the preview image to fit the original) using a template that also makes several thumbnail sizes. Transloadit then saves all the images to my S3 account and tells me the URL where it saved it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for my english,  I mean using PHP also.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)

Here are some [demos](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php).

Here is an [example](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/jcrop-extension-implementation-php-347.html) implementing in on PHP.